# Passing a Dictionary<int,Double> from Controller to view and access the dictionary values from View to display a chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, syncfusion

I have a controller that Populates a dictionary with key as Month dates as 0,5,10,15,20,25,30 and the Values as some Distance covered for each period. Say for eg: Dictionary element of key 5 has distance covered between days 0 and 5 of that Month.

```
Dictionary<int, double> ChartDetails = getDetails.getFMS1DataSet(FMS1Resultset);
```

I need to know how can I pass this dictionary from Controller to View.
In View I access them to display a chart of Number of Days VS distance covered. The Chart is SyncFusion User controls

```
@(Html.EJ().Chart("container")
          .PrimaryXAxis(pr => pr.Range(ra => ra.Min(2005).Max(2011).Interval(1)).Title(tl => tl.Text("Days")))
          .PrimaryYAxis(pr => pr.Title(tl => tl.Text("Fuel Usage")).RangePadding(ChartRangePadding.None)
          .LabelFormat("{value}%").Range(ra => ra.Min(25).Max(50).Interval(5)))
          .CommonSeriesOptions(cr => cr.Type(SeriesType.Line).EnableAnimation(true)
          .Marker(mr => mr.Shape(ChartShape.Circle).Size(sz => sz.Height(10).Width(10)).Visible(true)).Border(st => st.Width(2)))
          .Series(sr =>
              {
                  sr.Points(pt =>
                      {
                          pt.X("0").Y(0).Add();
                          pt.X("5").Y().Add();
                          pt.X("10").Y().Add();
                          pt.X("15").Y().Add();
                          pt.X("20").Y().Add();
                          pt.X("25").Y().Add();
                          pt.X("30").Y().Add();
                      }).Name("Fuel").Tooltip(sr1 => sr1.Visible(true).Template("Tooltip")).Add();

              })
          .CanResize(true)
```

Here for  pt.X("5").Y().Add(); I want the Y parameter to be added as Dictionary elements

Comment: Define your model as `Dictionary<int, double>`, then. Like this: `@model Dictionary<int, double>`. Then you can do something like `pt.X("0").Y(Model[0]).Add();` Though, this is not really optimal.. really need more details about what you're trying to accomplish (do you really want hard-coded x values?)

Comment: the X values are to be hardcoded. The Y values should come from the Dictionary for whcih the key will go as X value.

Comment: How can I define my model as Dictionary<int,Double>

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly pass the dictionary values from view to controller as dictionary doesn't allow serialization of data.
Hence we have created a view model class containing the dictionary  type.
The dictionary value is stored in the ViewBag in the controller  and passed to the view for assigning values to the series Points.
The X value in the chart should be of string type .Hence we have converted the integer Value  to string. Y values are used as double .
I have attached the sample link  for your reference.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/WebApplication11359635681